# window.open returns undefined in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

I have content script based Chrome extension. I initiate the sign in process through a popup window in the content script.

I open a popup window using the below code and then wait till its closed.

However, I get an 'undefined' from `window.open` method. Does anybody know why this happens?

`loginwin` is `undefined` in below code although the popup window opens up fine with the specified `login_url`. The code below is called from my content script.

```
var loginWin = window.open(login_url, 'LoginWindow', "width=655,height=490");
console.log(loginWin);
// Check every 100 ms if the popup is closed.
var finishedInterval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('checking if loginWin closed');
    if (loginWin.closed) {
        clearInterval(finishedInterval);
        console.log('popup is now closed');
        Backbone.history.navigate('index', true);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: you sure you have the _login_url_ variable declared somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, the popup opens up fine with the url specified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Note: This answer is obsolete. `window.open()` in a Chrome extension always returns either `null` (when the popup is blocked) or a `window` object. The information below only applies to very old (2012) versions of Chrome.

---

Content scripts do not have any access to a page's global `window` object. For content scripts, the following applies:

- The **`window`** variable does not refer to the page's global object. Instead, it refers to a new context, a "layer" over the page. The page's DOM is fully accessible. <sup>[#execution-environment](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment)</sup>

Given a document consisting of   `<iframe id="frameName" src="http://domain/"></iframe>`:

- Access to the contents of a frame is restricted by the [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) of the page; the permissions of your extension does not relax the policy.
- `frames[0]` and `frames['frameName']`, (normally referring to the the frame's containing global `window` object) is **`undefined`**.
- `var iframe = document.getElementById('frameName');`

  - **`iframe.contentDocument`** returns a **`document`** object of the containing frame, because content scripts have access to the DOM of a page. This property is **`null`** when the Same origin policy applies.
  - **`iframe.contentDocument.defaultView`** (refers to the `window` object associated with the document) is **undefined**.
  - **`iframe.contentWindow`**  is **undefined**.

As you can see, `window.open()` does not return a `Window` instance (neither does `window.opener`, and so forth).

---

#### Alternatives

- [Inject the code in the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879), so that it runs in the context of the page. Note: Only use this method if the page you're operating on can be trusted. To communicate between the injected script and the content script, you could use:

  ```
  var login_url = 'http://example.com/';
  var event_name = 'robwuniq' + Math.random().toString(16); // Unique name
  document.addEventListener(event_name, function localName() {
      document.removeEventListener(event_name, localName); // Clean-up
      // Your logic:
      Backbone.history.navigate('index', true);
  });
  // Method 2b: Inject code which runs in the context of the page
  var actualCode = '(' + function(login_url, event_name) {
      var loginWin = window.open(login_url, 'LoginWindow', "width=655,height=490");
      console.log(loginWin);
      // Check every 100 ms if the popup is closed.
      var finishedInterval = setInterval(function() {
          console.log('checking if loginWin closed');
          if (loginWin.closed) {
              clearInterval(finishedInterval);
              console.log('popup is now closed');
              // Notify content script
              var event = document.createEvent('Events');
              event.initEvent(event_name, false, false);
              document.dispatchEvent(event);
          }
      }, 1000);
  } + ')(' + JSON.stringify(login_url+'') + ', "' + event_name + '")';
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.textContent = actualCode;
  (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
  script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
  ```
- Launch the window from the background page using `window.open()`. This returns a `window` object which has a reliable `closed` property. See the next bullet point for more details on the communication flow.
- From the content script, [pass a message](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to the [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html). In the background page, use [`chrome.windows.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-create) to open a window. In the callback, assign an [`chrome.tabs.onRemoved`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onRemoved) and/or [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) event. When these event listeners are triggered, they should remove themselves, and notify the original caller (content script) using the `sendResponse` function of `chrome.extension.onMessage`.

Comment: @Rob...Thanks a lot for your detailed response. I have not tried your solution yet. I will try it during this weekend and mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks Rob, it works fine. This is the approach I followed, content_script sends a message to background script. Background scripts opens up a window and then waits for it close. The server then redirects the user to a login success page. The login success page closes the window. Once it closes, a message is sent back to content script. One thing I could not figure out was how would I know whether login process went through fine or not? Because user could have closed login window without logging in. I can requery the server for this, but somehow it does not sound neat.

Comment: You could insert a content script in the pop-up using `chrome.extension.executeScript` and `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` (filter: `status==='complete'`). Then, look in the document for an unique node which identifies a logged in status.

Comment: Great awnser, just a quick question (which I properly could read up on my self if i read thought all those pages), the reason for bullet 3 is only communication between the background page and the pop-up right?... If your just building a "Print view" over a page there should be no apparent reason to not just stick with solution 2 right?... Is that correct understooed, or is there any other drawbacks to that one?

Comment: The third bullet point addresses the question's requirement that the window's state (has it been closed?) has to be monitored. If you only want to open a window, use either `window.open();` *or* [`chrome.windows.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-create).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, Chrome was blocking the popup and the user had to unblock by clicking the "blocked popup" icon in the upper-right corner of the window. (They can also enable/disable exceptions under "Content settings..." in Chrome settings.)

I would suggest adding some code after window.open() so that the user knows what to do. For example:

```
if (!loginWin)
    alert("You must first unblock popups and try again for this to work!");
```